# Error with Poppler implementation with C++

Tags: c++, pdf, codeblocks, undefined-reference, poppler

I'm currently working on project which uses the poppler library. As It stands I have the following:

In the following folder (C:\Users\ ...\Anotation Extraction) I have all the files associated with a Codeblocks C++ project (including the main.cpp) as well as the current version of poppler and its associated documents in a folder called "poppler-0.22.2".
I also have a test pdf in this folder.
(System: Windows 7, 64 bit, Codeblocks using MinGW)

In my main.cpp file I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "poppler-0.22.2/cpp/poppler-document.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const string dir = "C:\\Users\\...\\test.pdf";

poppler::document* doc;
doc = poppler::document::load_from_file(dir);
delete doc;

cout << dir << endl;
return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to build this code, the following errors pop up and I have absolutely no idea why.

> obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
>
> C:\Users...\Anotation Extraction\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN7poppler8document14load_from_fileERKSsS2_S2_'|
>
> C:\Users...\Anotation Extraction\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN7poppler8documentD1Ev'|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|

Any help you guys could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Undefined reference is always linker error. Show how you call it.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how to link to the Poppler library as I haven't built it and there appears to be no prebuilt libraries available, unless I've missed them. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Well, that's simple: you have to link against the library. You'll either have to build it yourself or get compiled binaries elsewhere...